# Save image files in django-oscar database using S3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-oscar

I am using `django-oscar` in my current project and trying to save the media files in an s3 bucket. I am adding the products in default dashboard in `django-oscar`.

I am confused about how to save product images on s3 and the how to save image url in `Product` model. In order to achieve this, what should I do? Do I have to modify `Product` model and add a new field for image urls? Or tweaking STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL would be enough? 
Here is my media configuration.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, 'media')
```

Comment: You would need to use a storage backend that supports S3. Popular choices are [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) and [django-s3-storage](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage). Both provide instructions for how to configure a project to use S3 (which will work with Oscar).

Comment: Suppose I am using django-storages. How would I handle the file upload part? Do I have to override every view class which uploads an image and add my own logic to upload the image to s3?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything. Oscar uses Django's default handling of this, so you just need to configure your storage backend as per the documentation for these packages.